# PHP - foreach loop many times and create a new list

Tags: php, loops

I have an array with many values, I want to achieve a list like this with PHP.

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="thumb-cont">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="thumb-cont">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="thumb-cont">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

can any body help me how can i manage this list in foreach or for loop in php.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're generating HTML `<ul>` tags inside your PHP loop. Use the following code:

```
for($ind = 1; $ind <= 18; $ind++)
{
    if($ind <= 6) // Loop 1 through 6
    {
        // Add <ul> elements here.
    }

    else if($ind >= 7 && $ind <= 12) // Loop 7 through 12
    {
        // Add <ul> elements here.
    }

    else if($ind >=13 $ind <= 18) // Loop 13 through 18
    {
            // Add <ul> elements here.
    }
}
```

Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: The Answer from developerCK is better, because if you have more that 18 Elements, than in your solution you will have to add an another if-case.

Answer (score 6):

$arr is having 18 elements and $html will have all html string with ul

```
$len = count($arr);
$html = '<ul><div class="item"><div class="thumb">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if(!$i%6 && $i != 0){
        $html .= '</ul></div></div><ul><div class="item"><div class="thumb">';
    }

    $html .='<li>content</li>';
}
$html .='</ul></div></div>';
```

for 18 elements this will contain like

  6 elements

  6 elements

  6 elemnt

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($arrayElems as $elem) {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter < 6) {
        // build ul of first 6 elements
    }
    else if($counter < 12) {
        // build ul of next 6 elements
    }
    else {
        // build ul of next 6 elements
    }

}
```